# Names of columns in Data Frame

Tags: r

Suppose we have a dataframe  `data`  with the following column names:  `A1, A2, A3` . I want to check if any of the columns are  `0` . Instead of doing the following:

```
 if (data$A1 == 0 || data$A2 == 0 || data$A3 == 0)
    {
        print("TRUE")
    }
```

is there a way of doing something like this:

```
      for (i in 1:3)
         {
            if (data$Ai == 0)
              {
                print("TRUE")
              }
         }
```

How do you use indices in variable names?

Comment: Are you trying to check if any column equal to zero for each _row_?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variables with the `$` syntax. better to just subset the data.frame using column names as strings (which you can do) and then check if any are 0

```
any(data[, paste0("A", 1:3)]==0)
```

Comment: If some sort if indicator is needed in the original data set you can do this, then create `data_subset$dummy <- rep(1, nrow(data))` then merge that subsetted data back in to the original.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me whether you just want to know if any element of a column is equal to 0, if every element of a column is equal to 0, or what exactly you want.  That said, in my example/answer, you can change the function argument to look for what it is you want.

I would use the apply function as it can be more simple and fast than writing a loop.  The first argument is your dataframe, the second is 1 for rows, 2 for columns (what you want):

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,0,3),B=c(3,3,3),C=c(4,3,0)) # Replace with your data

# For if you just want to know if each column contains a 0
apply(df,2,FUN=function(x) max(x==0,na.rm=T)) 

# For if you just want to know how many 0s are in each column
apply(df,2,FUN=function(x) sum(x==0))

# For if you want to know if all entries in each column are 0
apply(df,2,FUN=function(x) all(x==0))

# etc.
```

These will returned named vectors where you can see what the answer is for each column by name.

I hope this helps!